# Standalone Java application with RESTFull API and static web

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

To my pom.xml I add one dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Main part of code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost").port(9998).build();

    //add test configs
    Set rest = new HashSet<Class>();
    rest.add(TestResource.class);
    final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(rest);

    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);


    try {
        //server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("web/"),"/w");

        server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/resources/web"),"/");

        server.start();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Press enter to stop the server...");
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        server.shutdownNow();
    }


}
```

I such case API is not working, but static web which is deployed to the "/" is working.
[Please  check this screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siR8A.png)

Then when I change a few line of code:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/resources/web"),"/www");
```

API and static web is working, but web isnt at "/" its at "/www". 
[Please check this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZXzD.png)

Can you please help me to get working API at "/api" and static web at "/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create baseuri like:

```
 final URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/api").port(9998).build();
```

Comment: Thank you. But didnt help :( then same.

Comment: Hmm, after this change it worked for me. What exactly you try to achieve? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this by including which extensions would you like to be managed by the static handler with a pattern like /*.jpg, *.html,...

This way the server should be able to select the appropiate handler.

Comment: Could you post your new configuration?

Comment: server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/resources/web/*"),"/www");

Comment: or like this 

server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/resources/web/*.html"),"/www");

Comment: I would eather try something like this StaticHttpHandler("src/main/resources/web/"),"/*.html");